# Get PayPal account history using REST

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I want to use Java PayPal SDK to get account history. I tried this simple code:

```
    public void randomDatabaseData() throws SQLException, FileNotFoundException, IOException, PayPalRESTException {
    String clientID = "test";
    String clientSecret = "test";

    String accessToken = null;
    try {
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("mode", "live");
        try {
            accessToken = new OAuthTokenCredential(clientID, clientSecret, map).getAccessToken();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(accessToken);
        transactionSearch(accessToken);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public TransactionSearchResponseType transactionSearch(String accessToken) {

    TransactionSearchReq transactionSearchReq = new TransactionSearchReq();
    TransactionSearchRequestType transactionSearchRequest = new TransactionSearchRequestType(
            "2012-12-25T00:00:00+0530");
    transactionSearchReq.setTransactionSearchRequest(transactionSearchRequest);
    PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService service = new PayPalAPIInterfaceServiceService();
    service.setTokenSecret(accessToken);

    TransactionSearchResponseType transactionSearchResponse = null;
    try {
        transactionSearchResponse = service.transactionSearch(transactionSearchReq);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Message : " + e.getMessage());
    }
    if (transactionSearchResponse.getAck().getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {

        Iterator<PaymentTransactionSearchResultType> iterator = transactionSearchResponse
                .getPaymentTransactions().iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            PaymentTransactionSearchResultType searchResult = iterator.next();

            System.out.println("Transaction ID : " + searchResult.getTransactionID());
        }
    } else {
        List<ErrorType> errorList = transactionSearchResponse.getErrors();
        System.out.println("API Error Message : " + errorList.get(0).getLongMessage());
    }

    return transactionSearchResponse;
}
```

But I get his error stack when I run the code:

```
    Error Message : configurationMap cannot be null
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.crm.web.tickets.GenearateTicketsTest.transactionSearch(GenearateTicketsTest.java:161)
    at com.crm.web.tickets.GenearateTicketsTest.randomDatabaseData(GenearateTicketsTest.java:139)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
```

How I can fix this code? I configure client ID and secret key into PayPal web site but still I get error.

Comment: Ever find a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you using [TransactionSearch](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/TransactionSearch_API_Operation_NVP/) API to get the payment history based on your search date range.

Comment: I updated the post but I get error. Do you know what configurationMap I need to use?